# After redirecting my js codes dont work until i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have got a main.html after redirecting to another page with include **JS codes** it doesn't work properly until i refresh the page , What is the solution?

**0.html**

```
<body data-theme="b">

  <div class="p2" data-role="page" id="p2">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed"><img src="images/head.png" alt="" class="head">
      <a href="#panel-overlay" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>

    </div>

    <div data-role="header">
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="padding:0;margin-top:-2px;">


      <div class='jAudio'>


  </div>

  <script src='resources/js/jaudio.min.js'></script>
  <script src='resources/js/0.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and there are two external js file jaudio and the 0.js , how can i make this page loaded once i redirect it to the page?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: but i have two external js which process that how can i do that

Comment: onload fires after everything has loaded. so you just need to call whatever functions you want to run in those scripts after onload.

Comment: i implemented that but still not working @nathanhayfield

Comment: can you please post your JS code also also if possible please indicate which JS function is not working

Comment: `doesn't work properly` - check the *browser **developer** console* for errors - the errors shown may provide useful information on why it doesn't work and what you did wrong

Comment: where is your code bro

Comment: @Farhan i found the solution and im gonna share it

Comment: @JaromandaX i checked them already the problem is the external codes dont loaf before you refresh the page and i find a solution for the ridirecting part.

Comment: @NancyMooree thanks for your interests bro

Comment: I've read your answer, and I'm completely at a loss at understanding what it is you think you are doing

Comment: at the main page before redirecting if you use _parent or _top in you <a> it help you to reload you redirected page properly without doing any change

Answer (score 0):

i was Searching a lot for finding the solution to this problem but most of them was pointing to recoding and using `.load()` or `.ready()` function to have the codes after Page loaded completely but no where point to the given solution! The easiest and the best way for having those codes Without changing anything is a small Trick. before redirecting, at the  tag we can easily use another options of target(as default it is `_self`)which block renewing page completely.so if you use `_parent` or `_top` the redirected page will be fully Reloaded and your js codes will work as well .